# Error by macro-defined underscript $A_b$

Tags: amsmath

I use macro \DeclarePairedDelimiterX to define a domain symbol $\mathbb{D}_f$ of map f. However, the Overleaf compiler refuses to accept it as valid.

```
\DeclarePairedDelimiterX{\domain}[1]{\mathds{D}}{}{{}_{#1}}
```

Error:

```
You need to enclose all mathematical expressions and symbols with special markers. These special markers create a ‘math mode’.
Use $...$ for inline math mode, and \[...\]or one of the mathematical environments (e.g. equation) for display math mode.

This applies to symbols such as subscripts ( _ ), integrals ( \int ), Greek letters ( \alpha, \beta, \delta ) and modifiers (\vec{x}, \tilde{x}).
```

Comment: you have tagged `amsmath` but that does not define `\DeclarePairedDelimiterX`. The arguments for left and right need to be dimiters that work with `\left..\right`  you can not use `\mathds{D}`

Comment: do you want `\newcommand\domain[1]{\mathds{D}_{#1}}` ?

Comment: Oh, I see. May you portrait this answer as post's?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The arguments for left and right need to be delimiters that work with
`\left..\right` you can not use `\mathds{D}` as left delimiter.

I suspect you want

```
\newcommand\domain[1]{\mathds{D}_{#1}}


$\domain{f}$
```